# Use "javax.crypto" library in a .JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, jar, libraries

At the beginning of the code of my java application, one class is called to decrypt resources (text files and images) using `javax.crypto` 
(These resources were encrypted in the same way).

In Eclipse, the application works well and resources are decrypted. But when I export it to a runnable .JAR file, nothing happens when I try to launch it. I added "jce.jar" library as an "External JAR" in my Build Path, but it still didn't work.

Here is the imports of my "Decrypt" class :

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.CipherOutputStream;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.DESKeySpec;
```

I usually use "Proguard" to obfuscate my JAR files, and when I launched it for this project, it showed :

> -Warning : library class `javax.security.auth.kerberos.KerberosKey` extends or implements program class `javax.crypto.SecretKey`
>
> -Warning : library class `javax.security.auth.kerberos.KeyImpl` extends or implements program class `javax.crypto.SecretKey`
>
> -Warning : there were 2 intances of library classes depending on program classes. You must avoid such dependencies, since the program classes will be processed, while the library classes will remain unchanged.

What are those classes, and how can I make my runnable JAR works ?

---

**EDIT**

Okay, I think I found one problem, caused by the way I determine paths of my encrypted and decrypted resources. But I don't know if it's the only problem I have, so I created another post !

(Link : [Paths and URL for ressources in a .JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38442653/paths-and-url-for-ressources-in-a-jar-file))

Comment: *Nothing* happens?

Comment: The application doesn't launch at all ! But when I use not encrypted resources, so without the decryption class, it works well..